# Java8 Stream Collectors - Splitting a list based on sum of values

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I am trying partition a list into multiple sublists based on a condition that sum of a particular field should be less than 'x'. Below is sameple code:

```
public class TestGrouping {
   public static class Transaction{
     String txnId;
     String comment;
     Amount amount;

    public Transaction(String txnId, String comment, Amount amount) {
        this.txnId = txnId;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}

public static class Amount{
     String amountValue;

    public Amount(String amountValue) {
        this.amountValue = amountValue;

    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Transaction> transactionList = new ArrayList<>();
    Transaction txn1 = new Transaction("T1","comment1",new Amount("81"));
    Transaction txn2 = new Transaction("T2","comment2",new Amount("5"));
    Transaction txn3 = new Transaction("T3","comment3",new Amount("12"));
    Transaction txn4 = new Transaction("T4","comment4",new Amount("28"));
    transactionList.add(txn1);
    transactionList.add(txn2);
    transactionList.add(txn3);
    transactionList.add(txn4);

//below is what i thought might work
//    transactionList.stream().collect(groupingBy (r->Collectors.summingInt(Integer.valueOf(r.amount.amountValue)),Collectors.mapping(t -> t, toList())));
}
```

The goal is to split the transactionList into 2 (or more) sublists - where the sum of 'amount' is less than 100. So i could have a sublist have only txn1 - having amount as 81; and the other sublist have txn2, txn3, txn4 (as sum of these is less 100). Other possibility is - have sublist1 having txn1, txn2, txn3; and another sublist with just txn4.  Not trying to create the most 'optimal' lists basically, just that sum of amounts should be less than 100.

Any clues?

Comment: since you depend on the "next" elements, this is only double with a custom collector - where the `accumulator` would not be very different of what you would do in a plain loop; while the `combiner` would be a bit more fun - but still pretty trivial

Answer (score 0):

The Idea is to use a custom collector to generate a list of pair(amountSum, transactions), the list should initialy be sorted. The accumulator method (here Accumulator.accept) do the grouping logic, I didn't implement combine because there is no need for a combiner in non parallel stream.
Bellow the code snippet, hope it helps.

```
    public class TestStream {

    public class Transaction {
        String txnId;
        String comment;
        Amount amount;

        public Transaction(String txnId, String comment, Amount amount) {
            this.txnId = txnId;
            this.comment = comment;
            this.amount = amount;
        }
    }

    public class Amount {
        String amountValue;

        public Amount(String amountValue) {
            this.amountValue = amountValue;

        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<Transaction> transactionList = new ArrayList<>();
        Transaction txn1 = new Transaction("T1", "comment1", new Amount("81"));
        Transaction txn2 = new Transaction("T2", "comment2", new Amount("5"));
        Transaction txn3 = new Transaction("T3", "comment3", new Amount("12"));
        Transaction txn4 = new Transaction("T4", "comment4", new Amount("28"));
        transactionList.add(txn1);
        transactionList.add(txn2);
        transactionList.add(txn3);
        transactionList.add(txn4);

        transactionList.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(tr -> Integer.valueOf(tr.amount.amountValue)))
            .collect(ArrayList<Pair<Integer, List<Transaction>>>::new, Accumulator::accept, (x, y) -> {
            })
            .forEach(t -> {
                System.out.println(t.left);
            });
    }

    static class Accumulator {
        public static void accept(List<Pair<Integer, List<Transaction>>> lPair, Transaction tr) {
            Pair<Integer, List<Transaction>> lastPair = lPair.isEmpty() ? null : lPair.get(lPair.size() - 1);
            Integer amount = Integer.valueOf(tr.amount.amountValue);
            if (Objects.isNull(lastPair) || lastPair.left + amount > 100) {
                lPair.add(
                    new TestStream().new Pair<Integer, List<Transaction>>(amount,
                        Arrays.asList(tr)));
            } else {
                List<Transaction> newList = new ArrayList<>();
                newList.addAll(lastPair.getRight());
                newList.add(tr);
                lastPair.setLeft(lastPair.getLeft() + amount);
                lastPair.setRight(newList);
            }
        }
    }

    class Pair<T, V> {
        private T left;
        private V right;

        /**
         * 
         */
        public Pair(T left, V right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        public V getRight() {
            return right;
        }

        public T getLeft() {
            return left;
        }

        public void setLeft(T left) {
            this.left = left;
        }

        public void setRight(V right) {
            this.right = right;
        }
    }

}
```